# Plotting hours of the day in x in matplotlib, overriding the automatic setting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with hours of the day and a column with body activity.  I want to plot the activity 'SVM' with hour in x from 12 midday to 12 midday the day after. However  the plot automatically plot from 00 to 23. This is 
part of the code after loading the file:

```
enter code here

In [16] x = act1[['Time1']].values

In [17] y= act1[['SVM']].values

In [18] y
Out[18]: 
array([[  11.63],
       [  12.13],
       [  12.14],
       ..., 
       [  86.37],
       [ 154.61],
       [ 127.49]])

In [19]  plt.plot(x,y)
Out[19]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x9e7f5c0>]
```

￼

Comment: I assume `x` is between 0 and 24. If so, you need to shift the first half of the  values (between 0 and 12), so that they come after the second half (between 12 and 24).

Comment: You could also convert the hour data to timestamps, with the 0-11 hours the day after the 12-23. Look up `import datetime`, etc.

Comment: You can make a new dataframe column or a list where you have mapped a given time (your 'Time1') to number of minutes since midday.  So midday would map to 0 and 11:59 (the next day) would map to 1439.  Now you can plot SVM on these new times.  Also, you could create the time labels as a list of strings.  If this is a terrible explanation see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30245793/4663466

Comment: Thank you for your advises. I will follow your lead. and post the results